# Mixfix-parser: finding associated tokens on a list

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, parsers, lexical-analysis

I've been trying to design an in-program programming language. Like any programming language, the input source code must go through various stages:

1. Divide the source code into tokens. (Tokenizer)
2. Parse the tokens into an abstract syntax tree (Parser)
3. Either interpret or compile the program etc.

With the 2nd step I don't get further, or I don't get it "nicely".
The problem is the following:
I have a list of tokens, for example:
`-` `1` `?` `2` `+` `3` `?` `4` `:` `5` `:` `6`

where there are the following operators defined somewhere:

`-_` `_+_` `_-_` `_?_` `_?_:_`

The `_` is a placeholder for some argument. So `_+_` takes two arguments, one on the left and one on the right side.
Since my programming language is supposed to support Mixfix-operators (e.g. ternary `_?_:_`), the parser has to figure out which tokens belong together.
It becomes problematic when the parser has to distinguish whether the `?` in the 3rd position belongs to the `_?_:_` operator, or to the `_?_` operator, etc.

Is there an algorithm or a data structure that makes it possible to find out whether there is exactly one solution (one operator per token)? I have tried in the past to use things like exclusion methods, but without any success. (I think algorithms, that require exponential time are not efficient for larger lists of tokens.)

Comment: The problem you are trying to solve have been solved efficiently and there exists a full research area that is now a CS classic, that is, formal languages. Specifically, context free languages. If you have a precise need that forces you to avoid it and design the parser from scratch keep going, conversely I would have a look at CFLs because they make parser generation much easier.